# upcalls to java from angularjs do only work after manual page refresh

Tags: java, angularjs, javafx

I'm using angularjs within the javafx webview component to build a small application.

I'm attaching the javascript bridge object using this code in a changelistener.

```
private void initJavaScriptBrige(){
    log.log(Level.INFO, "initializing javascript");
    JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
    window.setMember("javabridge", new JavaScriptBridge());
}

engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<State>() {
          @Override public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
              log.log(Level.INFO, "State chaged to {0} for page {1}", new Object[]{newState.name(), engine.getLocation()});
              if(newState.equals(State.SUCCEEDED)){
                  initJavaScriptBrige();
                  //check is the bridge exists
                  JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
                  Object java=window.getMember("javabridge");
                  log.log(Level.INFO, "java {0}", new Object[]{java==null?"does not exist":"exists"});
              }
          }
        }
    );
```

The JavaScriptBridge class has a public method named starttest. The class itself is a public class.

```
public class JavaScriptBridge {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JavaScriptBridge.class.getName());

    public String val="test";

    public JavaScriptBridge() {
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Bridge was created");
    }

    public void starttest(){
        log.log(Level.INFO, "starting test");
    }

}
```

In javascript (angularjs) I use this code to execute a command.

```
startTest(){
        if(window.javabridge){
            console.log("java exists "+(typeof window.javabridge)+" "+JSON.stringify(window.javabridge));
            if(window.javabridge.starttest){
                console.log("starttest exists");
                window.javabridge.starttest();
            }else{
                console.log("starttest does not exist");
                window.javabridge.starttest();
            }
        }else{
            console.log("java does not exist");
        }
    }
```

When I execute the starttest javascript method I get the following error message:

nov 24, 2016 10:50:12 AM be.azstlucas.cpr.view.Browser$1 messageAdded

INFO: java exists object {}

nov 24, 2016 10:50:12 AM be.azstlucas.cpr.view.Browser$1 messageAdded

INFO: starttest does not exist

nov 24, 2016 10:50:12 AM be.azstlucas.cpr.view.Browser$1 messageAdded

INFO: Error: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'window.javabridge.starttest()')

However if I reload the page using the right click option in the webview and rerun the method then for some reason the method does exist and is executed without any problem.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

Changing these lines of code solved my problem.

```
log.log(Level.INFO, "initializing javascript");
JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
window.setMember("javabridge", new JavaScriptBridge());
```

I've made the JavaScriptBridge a private final member of a class that executes this code.

Comment: Changing my bridge to a private final variable in the controller did it for me.  Then I found that just putting it in a variable adding it in the ChangeListener did it too.

Comment: In case it helps anybody: in your Java code, make sure to hold a reference to the bridge object. It took me some days of debugging to find out that otherwise, the bridge object will get garbage collected and not be accessible from Javascript. I don't know why, but my code worked without problem on linux but and MacOS the bridge object was GCed.

Comment: If found the explanation in [8u102 Update Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u102-relnotes-3021767.html) (scroll down to the changes section. It is explained under *Fixed memory leak when Java objects are passed into JavaScript*. It is an effect of fixing a [JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089681).